# why is there a margin in the end of screen when elements pass the screen height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image: This Is the screen shot of my projects before its pass the screen height]

[image: This Is the screen shot of my projects Aftrer its pass the screen height]

when I just passed the screen height suddenly a margin-end appears. I already tried
'''cover: 100% 100%''' and it doesn't make any sense because the image is shrinking because of that. and also I'm using bootstrap as my framework

I also tried,

'''width: 100%;
height: auto; '''

And it's also not working because when I add more elements height of the image increases its self for fit to the elements.

here is my CSS code:
'''
body {
background-image: url('Media Files/Images/JPG/BG\ photo\ of\ the\ home\ page.jpg');
background-size: cover;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-position: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: 'sen', sans-serif;
background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
'''

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the default margin and padding of all elements to 0 in your CSS? If you haven't, do that and see what happens. e.g

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It just doesn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
```

}

it's resolved when I put this css